# how can I force Android Automated device selection in the android device chooser with google api's in a project

Tags: android, google-api, adt

Launching an android project with google api's from eclipse invokes the device chooser. In project properties I have selected automatic selection of device however the device doesnt appear entirely compatible due to the project requiring google api's as seen here:

[image: error]

The device is a galaxy nexus and it has google maps installed.

How can I make starting the project on a device seemless. I am looking for a one click solution, click once on the project and it starts on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this problem. Its a bug in the android development tools. Its been around and unfixed since 2010..

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11373

Answer (score 0):

Use adb install command

```
adb install [-l] [-r] [-s] <file> -push this package file to the device and install it
                             ('-l' means forward-lock the app)
                             ('-r' means reinstall the app, keeping its data)
                             ('-s' means install on SD card instead of 
                                   internalstorage)
```

Comment: This method will install an apk but how will it help me automatically  install, and run an apk?